# WPF MVVM: Decouple view bindings and dynamically setting bindings

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm writing a fairly large WPF application that is following the MVVM structure. I would like to run my UI in basically 2 modes. The first being the normal day-to-day operational mode. The second is one that I've been wondering about for a while now...I would like to be able to run it in a "configure" mode where the user will see the UI in more or less the same fashion as the normal mode, except that a popup window would appear when they hover over (or maybe click) a control. This popup would allow the user to change certain bindings related to that control. I don't want to expose every property (or every control).

For example:
There is a TextBlock that has a binding to a pressure signal, now that user wants to change this binding to a temperature signal. They could start the UI in config mode, navigate to the screen with the TextBlock, select it, and see the Text property in a popup which they can then change to the new temp signal. This is a simplified exampe, but basically what I'm looking to do.

Is this possible? Remember the UI would have to write to the the View (XAML). Any help is appreciated.

P.S.
This would be a very useful but rarely used feature. It would be ok to maybe have 2 projects which ustalize the same View but different ViewModels and Models...at least that's what I've been thinking might be needed. Even if the normal mode UI would have to be recompiled after using the configure mode UI.

Comment: Handle this at the ViewModel level, instead of trying to hack the UI for this. You need to abstract your Views and Create a Model representation of these "widgets". The UI cannot be persisted (in a database, for example). Therefore you need something else.

Comment: You're saying you'd like to change the binding so that it is permanently bound to something else?

Comment: Otherwise, have your XAML files deployed with the application (instead of compiled into) and have them loaded at runtime with `XamlReader.Load()` or something, then you can modify the XAML files (on disk).

Answer (score 0):

Every popup window should have its own VM (or they could share if it turns out to be an overkill due to small number of properties per popup) and communicate with the main VM via the message bus.

Store your bindings as User Settings and when the message arrives from the popup window VM, carrying the new binding as a payload, main VM would get that payload and save the appropriate user setting by simply calling `Settings.Default.Save();`

Based on your description, no reason to make it more complicated than that IMO...